# Facebook FB.api Notication stopped working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

```
FB.api(/userid/notifications,'post',{access_token:{appid}|{appsecret},template:"our text"},function (response){console.log(response);});
```

The above is how we are using to send notification to user registered in our app. The response is success true but still the user does not get the notification. I created a demo app and tried the above code which returned success true and it did send notification, what could be the issue.

What am I doing wrong? The code was working when I checked a day or two back and nothing was changed.

Comment: are you using that code on the client? because that would be a major security issue, with the app secret out in the open...

Comment: @luschn yes i got it i will change it, once the notifications started to work. currently the notifications from my app are not shown in facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote the code for you using JS .

```
  FB.api('/userid/notifications', 'post', {
access_token: '42424242424242|42abc42abc42abc42abc42abc42abc',
template: 'David Augustus wrote a code for you !'}, function(response) {
    alert(response);
  });
```

It's great because i would need to do that in a couple weeks anyway .

I just tested it, using an App with Game category and using an App in other categories .

It worked both ways :)

But, once again, if you want all your users receiving spammy notifications, you must pass this code at your app main page, so will have that faster .

Please only use this code after reading 
[Best pratices from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications#bestpractices) at least 3 times .

On Facebook Best Pratices : "send one or two notifications to people each" ..

Change the word "day" for "month" .

If someone asks, it wasn't me who helped you :P

Comment: You can also try using other parameters, as href, ref and type .

Comment: Thanks alot David I will give this a try and see if this works. I will get back in few minutes.

Comment: Nope :( it's same throws success status but no notification on facebook. Does marking an app as spam cause such behavior, because when i checked my facebook notification history. All the notifications related to my app disappeared from the list. I doubt that may be because someone marked it as spam.

Comment: So the problem is not on the code, i tested it using Facebook JS console, and i suggest you test using Facebook JS Console also, and using an app access token that i generated on the graph explorer. Not the APP ID and (NEVER) the SECRET as you mentioned ..

Comment: Just a minute I will check one more thing

Comment: You can also try with another app, for having sure that its not disabled by the platform because of spam. Does not need to use a Game. Is your app at Facebook Canvas? Are you checking for notifications on desktop or only at mobile? I think it redirects user only for the canvas, so it would be not necessary to show the notification if you are under mobile app ..

Comment: Lol. Thank you. But what was the "one more thing" ?

Comment: My test app isn't a canvas app.

Comment: Oh, sure. I think about that before, but as i dont code for mobile yet, i was not sure .. Testing the code before think on other possibilities (concept). Please use that with conscience .

Comment: Yes thank you. I guess the issue still remains with my main app. I will check and let you know in a while.

Comment: I would try to do the same, as i sayd, i was thinking about using notifications instead of opening an popup for user set the profile picture, after generating and posting it;. But its necessary to create some kind of redirection, passing the ID and href. Its a lot complicated. You can message me at fb.me/davidaugustus42 so we can share more .

Comment: sure i will drop you a message.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same issue some days ago, but i use PHP and with an array of IDs .

I tried everything to fix it, and it looked like very difficult, now i'm sure they had changed something .

I could send some notifications, using another call, with no array of ids, once i think some of ids could uninstall the app .. i could send some notifications .

It still working but i think you probably will need to change (update) something on your code before production .

Problem is that i have no idea on why this is happening, once my code is PHP and the issue is  one array of ids, but the same ids work, with more requests, instead of batch requests ... one, two, three ids on the same call, worked .

I dont remember it very well.. I was very tired, many hours testing it, and as i sayd my code is very different of yours .

Have you tried to specify the API version on your call ?
And use to use "" or '' on all parameters of this kind of call .
Something like :

```
FB.api( "/v2.1/id/notifications", "POST" {});
```

I used this kind of notification only a few times, and last time i did a complete use of it, passing an ID, so when user clicks, app gets the ID (or anything you wanna pass), for example, GET FREE COINS NOW ..........

I was planning to use it another way this time, notificating the users that another image is avaiable for seting as profile picture, and linking it to mobile interface, it would be easly to users to set profile picture, after the app experience. Thats what i was wondering .

I think.. This notifications are a kind of... weird thing ..
But if used correctly, re engage users very well .
Anyway ..

Facebook is always changing some things because of necessary reasons .

Comment: Thank David. I tried changing the versions but nothing fruitful. Facebook surely changes something I don't know what it is. Javascript SDK uses https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js. So there won't be a requirement for update I guess. Does this have something to do with permissions. The notifications were working fine a few days ago.

Comment: Exactly, using PHP sdk was also working a few days ago, thats the most 'extrange part' of it. I dont think about the permissions, because i was using an APP access token, and it works with that. But the user must be logged in. I just notice that you pass "appsecret", dont you think thats an security issue that could make Facebook change something? I dont know where do you use it, but if users can access it, i wouldnt do that even with app acess token .

Comment: That's great can I see it.